# Bootstrap 4 datatable Javascript libaries 2019

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have created a table in bootstrap 4 and have populated it in my website with data from myphpadmin database using php/sql. However, i am looking to use the javascript libraries to implement search, Pagination, next page etc.

I have already tried numerous scripts and css libraries and none of them appear to be working so i am starting to think that there may be an issue with my coding. This is shown below:

```
<!--stylesheets-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel ="sylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/font-awesome.css" >
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">


<!--scripts-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type ="text/javascript" src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- main body of webpage that will contain table of patients-->

<div class='container mt-5 pt-5'>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered patientsTable" style="width: 100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                        <th scope="col">DOB</th>
                        <th scope="col">Address</th>
                        <th scope="col">Town</th>
                        <th scope="col">Postcode</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

<?php

    while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowid = $row['id'];
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $surname = $row ['surname'];
        $dob = $row['dob'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $town = $row['town'];
        $postcode = $row['postcode'];


        echo"
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>$firstname</td>
                    <td>$surname </td>
                    <td>$dob</td>
                    <td>$address</td>
                    <td>$town</td>
                    <td>$postcode</td>
                    <td><a class = 'btn btn-danger' href ='patientsmedication.php?editid=$rowid'>View</a></td>
                </tr>";

    }
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('.patientsTable').DataTable();
    } );
    </script>
```

I am looking for the search bar and other features to be implemented but at the moment it is just a plain table with the information from the database. 
Any help would be gratefully appreciated as i have spent half a day looking at this small issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, it seems that you have loaded jQuery twice in your code. You should remove any one from below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also you are making `tbody` multiple time which you should avoid and keep `tbody` outside the loop as below code:

```
<?php
    echo '<tbody>';
    while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowid = $row['id'];
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $surname = $row ['surname'];
        $dob = $row['dob'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $town = $row['town'];
        $postcode = $row['postcode'];


        echo"
                <tr>
                    <td>$firstname</td>
                    <td>$surname </td>
                    <td>$dob</td>
                    <td>$address</td>
                    <td>$town</td>
                    <td>$postcode</td>
                    <td><a class = 'btn btn-danger' href ='patientsmedication.php?editid=$rowid'>View</a></td>
                </tr>";

    }
?>
</tbody>
```

Also, you have 6 columns in your table `thead` but you are populating 7 column in `tbody` which will break your `HTML` code and `jQuery` as well. You either need to provide 7 column in `thead` or need to remove 1 column from `tbody`.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: thank you for your quick response and for taking time to answer but i implemented all above mentioned changes and it still did not apply the desired changes

Comment: Can you build a jsfiddle for this or show console if there is any error??

Comment: it is now working thanks. I have an onclick function with ajax and when clicked on the table appears but i need to click on the button a second time for the search bar etc to appear. I know this is a different question so i am not expecting an answer it is something i will look into. Many thanks again for your help